# The object "VoiceCall" can't be updated through a flow - When creating a package version

Tags: permission-sets, unlocked-package, service-cloud-voice, amazon-connect-salesforce-cti

We have stumbled upon `The object "VoiceCall" can't be updated through a flow.` error when introducing the required metadata for our Service Cloud Voice with BYOT (Bring Your Own Telephony - Amazon). For our CI builds we have added the permission set to the user in the Scratch org as instructed [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000J5rG9SAJ).

The issue now comes when we try to create a package version. We're getting exactly the same issue and we can't seem to add anything so we can push our flow. We have already explored adding `"apexTestAccess"` to our `sfdx-project.json` file, as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_unpackaged_md.htm). How can we add the relevant permission (`ContactCenterAdminExternalTelephony`) when building the package version?

Answer (score -2):

Try convert the flow action to apex invocable action and then try adding apexTestaccess in **sfdx-project.json**

```
"apexTestAccess": {
               "permissionSets": [
                   "Permission_Set_1",
                   "Permission_Set_2"
               ],
               "permissionSetLicenses": [
                   "SalesConsoleUser"
               ]
           }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/189192)